# UITableViewCell: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: Change button background per cell on a certain action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have table view that rendering cells. I created the cell once and reuse it. In each cell there is a button to do vote action for a place. On the vote action I want to change the background image of the button. When I click on the button in a certain cell the background image changes, but when I scroll down I find another button with the changed background image. I believe that the problem is because I'm using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` but I can't find a way to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
// .h file

@interface VotePlaceView : UIView < UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    VotePlaceView *votePlaceCell;

}
```

and in the implementation file

```
// .m File
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"votePlaceCell"];

    if (cell)
    {
        votePlaceCell = (VotePlaceView*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    }

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"votePlaceCell"];

        //GlobalObjects is a customised thing for me to load the cell in different languages 
        votePlaceCell = [[GlobalObjects loadNibNamed:@"votePlaceCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

        votePlaceCell.tag = 10;
        [cell addSubview:votePlaceCell];

    }


        .
        . //Fill data in the cell 
        .

    //This gives different IDs, no ID like the others (unique ID)
    NSLog(@"ID %d", [[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue]);

    UIButton* voteButton = (UIButton*)[votePlaceCell viewWithTag:20];

    voteButton.tag = [[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)votePlace:(UIButton *)sender
{
     // I tried two ways to achieve my point with no luck 
    //Selected case give the new background image

    //THE FIRST WAY 
    sender.selected = YES;

    //OR THE SECOND WAY
    UIButton* newVotePlace;
    newVotePlace = (UIButton*)[[sender superview] viewWithTag:sender.tag];
    newVotePlace.selected = YES;
}
```

Any idea?

**The Solution**

@Akhilrajtr's answer solved my problem, after I made some changes to his answer. Here is the solution, in case if anyone faced the same problem.

Instead of using a UIButton, I used UIButton and UIImageView. I put the UIImageView behind the UIButton and I give the UIImageView two images in the default case and in the highlighted case. I cleared the background image of the UIButton and then followed the accepted answer as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      .
      .

    int placeId = [[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];

    UIButton* voteButton = (UIButton*)[votePlaceCell viewWithTag:20];
    if (!voteButton) {
        voteButton = (UIButton*)[votePlaceCell viewWithTag:placeId];
    }
    voteButton.tag = [[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];
    if ([selectedIdArray containsObject:[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"]]) {

        UIImageView* voteImage;
        voteImage = (UIImageView*)[votePlaceCell viewWithTag:11];
        voteImage.highlighted = YES;
    } else {
        UIImageView* voteImage;
        voteImage = (UIImageView*)[votePlaceCell viewWithTag:11];
        voteImage.highlighted = NO;
        voteButton.selected = NO;
    }

    return cell;

}

-(IBAction)votePlace:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [selectedIdArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]];

    UIImageView* voteImage;
    voteImage = (UIImageView*)[[sender superview] viewWithTag:11];
    voteImage.highlighted = YES;
}
```

Comment: you have to keep track of clicked buttons or its ID's

Comment: Yes I know and this is what I did, I changed the button tag for each cell by the unique place ID

Comment: @SawsanAlKhdair what is you votePlacesResults array.?

Comment: Once the vote Button was pressed set a BOOL isSelected = true; save it in DB. Then if the table is reloaded take value from DB and show up in tableview.

Comment: @santhu votePlacesResults array is the response from the server of the places that I want to show in the table view

Comment: @manigandasaravanan If I understood your point correctly, I don't want to reload the table, I need the action to be done on the click immediately without reloading the table. Is this what you meant?

Comment: did you asking about the button action?..

Comment: @manigandasaravanan I want to change the background image of the button when the user click on it, this works fine for me, but when I scroll down I found another button its background has been changed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Create a `NSMutableArray *selectedIdArray` (don't forget to instatiate selectedIdArray in `viewDidLoad:`) to store selected ID's , and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     .
     .
     //Other codes
     .
     .

     NSLog(@"ID %d", [[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue]);
     int placeId = [[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];
     UIButton* voteButton = (UIButton*)[votePlaceCell viewWithTag:20];
     if (!voteButton) {
          voteButton = (UIButton*)[votePlaceCell viewWithTag:placeId];
     }
     voteButton.tag = [[[self.votePlacesResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];
     if ([selectedIdArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:placeId]) {
          voteButton.selected = YES;
     } else {
          voteButton.selected = NO;
     }
     return cell;
}
```

and in

```
-(IBAction)votePlace:(UIButton *)sender
{
     [selectedIdArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]];
     sender.selected = YES;
}
```

Comment: In this line [selectedIdArray addObject:sender.tag]; ... I'm getting this error: Implicit conversion of NSInteger to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, your solution is worked for me but after I did some changes, like adding a UIImageView behind the original UIButton and I played with image highlighted case instead of sender.selected and I removed the background of the UIButton so I can see the image behind it

Answer (score 1):

You need to store an array containing information about the background for each cell, and set the background for each cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

As you're using selected on the button, create an `NSMutableArray` with as many entries as the cells, and instead of setting the button itself to selected, change the `bool` on the selected index of the array, then you can set `selected` dependent on the value of the desired index of `NSMutableArray` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Got it, let me try it and get back to you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's the same idea of the answer that I accepted but his answer helped me more because of the code.